# Calculating a limit with infinitely many terms

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

I've encountered this limit :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+\cdots+\sin{\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}}\right)$$

Wolfram gives the value: $2\over \pi$.

We did something similar in class.
If I consider the function: $\sin(x\pi)$ and the equidistant partition: $j\over n$, I can somehow transform this problem into an integral.

Could someone please give me some advices and\or guidance on how to proceed in this problem.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

**edit:** Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @user_of_math We havent't covered that yet. I believe there's and alternative solution. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Riemann sum for the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \sin(\pi x)\,dx.
$$
The partition is $0,\dfrac1n,\dfrac2n,\dfrac3n,\ldots\dfrac n n$, so that $\Delta x$ is $1/n$ in each case.  Take the value of the function $x\mapsto\sin(\pi x)$ at the left endpoint of each subinterval.

Answer (score 2):

The expression whose limit you want to compute is a Riemann sum for the integral
$$
\int_0^1\sin(\pi\,x)\,dx.
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:-

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sin \left(\dfrac{i\pi}{n}\right)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^1\sin (\pi x) \ dx$